# npm run prod doesn't enable production mode on vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack

I'm using Laravel with Vuejs. I wanted to publish my website but I keep getting this message in the browser console.

> You are running Vue in development mode.
>   Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
>   See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

I executed npm run prod and cleared cache on my browser (chrome) but I still keep getting this message.
My **webpack.mix.js** looks like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? 'vue/dist/vue.min.js' : 'vue/dist/vue.js'
        }
    }
}

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

This is from my package.json:

```
 "prod": "npm run production",
 "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

This is what I get when I execute npm run prod

```
> @ prod /var/www/html/clash
> npm run production


> @ production /var/www/html/clash
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-    progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`


 DONE  Compiled successfully in 17705ms                                                                                                                                                                                                6:29:11 PM

                                                                                              Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                                                                                   /css/app.css   225 KiB       0  [emitted]         /js/app
                                                                                     /js/app.js   515 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
   fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.eot?    088a34f78f530102fd9661173b4a4f26   129 KiB          [emitted]
   fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.svg?    d72293118cda50ec50c39957d9d836d0   692 KiB          [emitted]  [big]
   fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.ttf?    273dc9bf9778fd37fa61357645d46a28   129 KiB          [emitted]
 fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.woff2?    822d94f19fe57477865209e1242a3c63  74.2 KiB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.woff?    f4920c94c0861c537f72ba36590f6362    87 KiB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.eot?    3ac49cb33f43a6471f21ab3df40d1b1e  33.6 KiB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.svg?    d2e53334c22a9a4937bc26e84b36e1e0   141 KiB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.ttf?    ece54318791c51b52dfdc689efdb6271  33.3 KiB          [emitted]
fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.woff2?    9efb86976bd53e159166c12365f61e25  13.3 KiB          [emitted]
 fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.woff?    a57bcf76c178aee452db7a57b75509b6  16.4 KiB          [emitted]
    fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.eot?    7fb1cdd9c3b889161216a13267b55fe2   190 KiB          [emitted]
    fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.svg?    7a5de9b08012e4da40504f2cf126a351   829 KiB          [emitted]  [big]
    fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.ttf?    2aa6edf8f296a43b32df35f330b7c81c   189 KiB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff2?    f6121be597a72928f54e7ab5b95512a1  74.3 KiB          [emitted]
   fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff?    93f284548b42ab76fe3fd03a9d3a2180  96.7 KiB          [emitted]

┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                npm update check failed                 │
│          Try running with sudo or get access           │
│          to the local update config store via          │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/umut/.config │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                npm update check failed                 │
│          Try running with sudo or get access           │
│          to the local update config store via          │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/umut/.config │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From this side the procedure seems correct, how did you include webpack compiled resources in laravel blade?

Comment: @RoccoMilluzzo I included it like this:

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

Comment: @RoccoMilluzzo I added the output of npm run prod to the question. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: try this <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

Comment: Simple pre-debug check that's important to get out of the way: did you remember to tell the browser to bypass cache, so that it doesn't keep using your whatever out-of-date bundle it has cached and instead loads the current one?

Comment: @RoccoMilluzzo npm run prod with <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
worked but I still get the same message on the browser console

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans On chrome I checked the checkbox "disable cache" on the network tab. So I guess the cache isn't the problem.

Comment: did you reload the page with the inspector opened and bypass cache? Ok I just red you did

Comment: I noticed something interesting..
On the network tab in chrome I can see the size of app.js which is 166kb but the size which npm run prod did output is 515kb.  


This is from npm run prod

Comment: /js/app.js   515 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app

Comment: simple second test: your webpack config is just another JS file (rather than a passive config), so console log the content of your `process.env`: let's not guess at what might be wrong until you run out of "things you can directly verify" =)

Comment: also: it's 2020, we haven't had to use `node_modules/somepackage/bin/cliutilname.js` for literally years now. Just say `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --no-progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.mix.js ` -- and on that note: **use your own config**, your script points to a laravel thing deep inside node_modules right now. Why?

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly mean. I added console.log(process.env) to webpack.mix.js and got a lot of information. They look ok but I don't get what I have to look for.
What do you mean with your second post?
Sorry but I'm a beginner and trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.
This was in my layout blade template:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

:facepalm:

Sorry for being stupid.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone has the same problem, I solved this problem by change

```
window.Vue = require('vue/dist/vue');
```

to

```
window.Vue = require('vue/dist/vue.min');
```

I'm using Vue 2.6.4